# RKObjectRequestOperation and caching

Tags: ios, caching, afnetworking, restkit

I'm calling a GET request with the following code:

```
RKObjectManager *manager = ...;
RKObjectRequestOperation* operation = [manager appropriateObjectRequestOperationWithObject:object method:method path:path parameters:parameters];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        }];
[manager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];
```

Only the first request is performed while all the following return a 200 HTTP status code without being executed (I've checked with a network proxy).
As it seems to be a cache related issue, I've temporarily modified the AFHTTPClient class adding:

```
request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData;
```

in the requestWithMethod implementation.

This way it works, so it's definitely caused by the cache.

Has anybody experienced any similar issue?
How could I modify my code?

Many thanks,
DAN

Comment: Why do you want to ignore the cache headers returned from the server?

Comment: Hi Wain, unfortunately I cannot change the server-side implementation but I need to get updated data every time

Comment: Then what you're doing is correct